# Access Denied when attempting to create bucket in AWS w/ Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am going through a bootcamp and one project is to create a bucket in aws using python scripting. I keep getting an access denied error and im not sure why? Any help would be much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJlB5.png)

Comment: Please past code as text in a code block along with error messages. Not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

@samrah there are many different scenarios to Access Denied

Major, your admin(in case if someone gives access to AWS), not gave permission to CREATe bucket

Other probably the Access Keys issue.

It's a good way always to share code snippet, so the community will help easily.